# HintPath on a added reference in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, build-process

I know that I can add a **HintPath** to an external DLLs to help Visual Studio/TFS find the dll when it builds.

What I was wondering is... is it possible to add multiple **HintPath**?

For example... developers have their DLLs for one place and we do a GetLatest of those DLLs at a different place on the server hence the need for multiple **HintPath**.

What do you think, world?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This answer is no longer valid. As [Sardaukar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462564/hintpath-on-a-added-reference-in-visual-studio/462650#comment16281588_462650) says, **Visual Studio always blindly uses the last HintPath**. [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13417794/105971) supports this.

---

Alright. I'm faster than Stackoverflow this time. I tried to add it and it seems to work fine.

So multiple HintPath IS possible.

When you have this:

```
<Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition.Codeplex">
    <HintPath>..\..\..\MEF2_Preview2\bin\System.ComponentModel.Composition.Codeplex.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

You can simply add more hint path like that:

```
<Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition.Codeplex">
    <HintPath>..\..\..\MEF2_Preview2\bin\System.ComponentModel.Composition.Codeplex.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath>D:\MEF\System.ComponentModel.Composition.Codeplex.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Did you just add multiple HintPath entries, or have multiple paths in a single entry?

Comment: if single entry, was it comma seperated or semicolon?

Comment: Could you please tell us how it is possible?

Comment: To do this, I close the solution, open the project file in Notepad (it ends with .csproj), then you will see the above code.

Comment: (Found this question when resolving an issue with hintpaths and I have to correct the above answer). Your answer is flawed. Yes, you can add multiple hintpaths manually to your csproj file, but Visual Studio will only use the last hintpath element. It probably works in your situation because your second hintpath can be resolved. Try it by swapping your hintpaths so that d:\MEF\System.ComponentModel.Composition.CodePlex.dll is the first. Then compile. You will probably see that Visual Studio will now try to reference the last hintpath.

Comment: @jon-eric I appreciate what you're trying to do, but a simple disclaimer with handy links is all that's needed. Explicitly calling for downvotes or upvotes in a big disclaimer like that is a dangerous path to set out on.

Comment: This solution even you declare multiple path the last one is going to be used, The solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/26738355/1342491 makes more sense since the path used is according to some condition.

Answer (score 43):

Sorry, you **can't** use multiple HintPath's.  Visual Studio/MSBuild takes only the **last** `<HintPath>` definition and will ignore any previous ones. Confirmed in VS2010 and VS2012.

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one, since the other one is giving false information.

Comment: You can use multiple HintPath's with a Condition on each. Check my answer below.

Comment: Confirmed that only the last HintPath is used in VS2015 too.

Answer (score 9):

You can use environment variables for that. E.g.

```
<Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition.Codeplex">
    <HintPath>$(PathToDLLs)\MEF2_Preview2\bin\System.ComponentModel.Composition.Codeplex.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Answer (score 9):

Using Condition you can:

```
<Reference Include="TheAssembly">
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\..\..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\..\..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\..\..\..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    etc...
</Reference>
```

The last HintPath where the Condition evaluates to true will be used.

Comment: Does this work with the above observation about the last hintpath being taken?  Does it ignore hintpaths with false conditions and take the last one with a true value?

Comment: It ignores all but the last one where the condition is true.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to the bottom of your project file just after the commented out targets section:

```
<Target Name="BeforeResolveReferences">
  <CreateProperty Value="YOUR_FIRST_PATH;YOUR_SECOND_PATH;$(AssemblySearchPaths)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="AssemblySearchPaths" />
  </CreateProperty>
</Target>
```

Replacing `YOUR_FIRST_PATH` and `YOUR_SECOND_PATH` with your paths.

It's important this goes after the following line or your setting will be overwritten:

`<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />`

With the `$(AssemblySearchPaths)` entry at the end of the string DLLs in your paths will override the normal resolution. If you move it to the beginning then the normal resolution is tried first and the additional paths are checked for any that weren't found. Normal resolution includes `<HintPath>` sections so there is no need to remove them if your paths come first.