# .csproj multiple hint paths for an assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, csproj

I'm packaging example code for an SDK distribution.  In the distribution, the relative path from code to the SDK assemblies is different from the build machine.  For example:

**Distribution**

```
csharp/bin/assembly.dll
example/ex1/ex1.csproj
```

**Build Machine**

```
foo/sdk/csharp/bin/assembly.dll
bar/baz/quux/ex1/ex1.csproj
```

Assume that I can't move anything.  Is there a way I can instruct `ex1.csproj` to look in both

`../../csharp/bin/` **and** `../../../../foo/sdk/csharp/bin/` for `assembly.dll`?

In C++ I'd put the dependency path in a standalone property sheet and distribute a different version with the SDK.  But C# doesn't have property sheets, and I don't want to maintain two versions of the full project.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462564/hintpath-on-a-added-reference-in-visual-studio) which states that I can't use multiple `<HintPath>` tags, so I'm looking for another way to approximate the same behavior.

Comment: Just add a property to the .csproj file and use it in the HintPath.  You can override its value on the build machine with the msbuild.exe /p option.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found a hacky solution that works for my case, where the parent directory is guaranteed to be different somewhere up the tree:

```
<Choose>
  <When Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\example')">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="Assembly ...">
        <HintPath>..\..\csharp\bin\assembly.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
  <Otherwise>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="Assembly ...">
         <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\foo\sdk\csharp\bin\assembly.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

Comment: `<HintPath Condition="">` from Wolf5 answer below is betterer.

Comment: @berkus I think this answer is better for larger projects with a lot of references. You can add and remove references without having to add the directory condition each time and it looks cleaner imo.

Comment: This answer is better for my scenario that some fundamental library-projects (eg text-processing libraries) are referenced by both main-level project (eg webapp) and second-level projects (eg data-layer libraries)

Answer (score 134):

The simplest way since only ONE HintPath can be used is to use the all-so-nice Condition attribute like this:

```
<Reference Include="TheAssembly">
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\..\..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\..\..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\..\..\..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    etc...
</Reference>
```

So the answer to the question would be this:

```
<Reference Include="assembly">
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\csharp\bin')">..\..\csharp\bin\assembly.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\..\..\foo\sdk\csharp\bin')">..\..\..\..\foo\sdk\csharp\bin\assembly.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

If multiple conditions matches, the last one will be used.

Comment: how about this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/184718/Take-advantage-of-Reference-Paths-in-Visual-Studio

Comment: Yup. I think that would work as well. Same answer as Filip has written.

Comment: I think this breaks as soon as more than one condition is truthy. That is, when both `csharp\bin` and `..\..\foo\sdk\csharp\bin` exist.

Comment: I does not break if that was to happen, as Visual Studio takes the first or last. It ignores that you have multiple as if the extras did not exist.

Comment: HI , excellent i was looking for the same solution , i need one more info like can we check if a variable value is true in some text file then load the one dll and if false the other dll ?

Comment: To do that you would probably need to create a function in your .csproj using the <UsingTask> tag that ouputs is true or false. Then run it it before the <Reference> task and check on its output in the Condition attribute. (example of usingtask: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548851/msbuild-usingtask-resolve-references)

Comment: @Wolf5 can you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34059733/multiple-hint-paths-in-csproj-file-from-an-text-file-variable

Comment: Amazing. Been having so much trouble with a project that was shared between multiple solutions. Thanks.

Comment: I think it is also worth mentioning that in case more than one such conditions are  evaluated as true the LAST true condition in the list of HintPaths will be used by Visual Studio. It looks like that true conditions are overriding each other while they are being processed one by one. I haven't tried it with MSBuild yet but I assume it's the same.

Comment: Here is a Regex find+replace I used to accommodate NuGet references in projects that are shared in two solutions, where the second solution is nested in a subfolder of the first solution:
---
find:  ^(.*?)<HintPath>(.*?)packages(.*?)</HintPath>$
---
replace: $1<HintPath Condition="Exists('..\packages')">..\packages$3</HintPath>\n$1<HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\packages')">..\..\packages$3</HintPath>

Answer (score 8):

I am using this solution without any problem:

```
<Reference Include="log4net">
  <HintPath>
     $(SolutionDir)packages\log4net.2.0.8\lib\net45-full\log4net.dll
  </HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Got it from here: 
[use hint paths relative answer from LeonidVasilyev](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/738)

Answer (score 7):

Add the secondary path as follows to the general property group. in the csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ReferencePath>..\..\..\..\..\foo\sdk\csharp\bin\</ReferencePath>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

The `ReferencePath` property is intended to be specified when executing MsBuild, but it will work fine like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could subst the `/csharp/bin` folder into a drive (differently on each machine), for example `X:` and then reference `X:\` or `X:\bin` on both machines, as the path will now be the same.

Comment: This is too complicated.  The SDK user must be able to unzip the SDK, open the example project, and compile it with no extra steps.

Comment: I would still go along the same way - using user's SDK path as reference and do some folder links trickery on build machine to make it run there too

Comment: That means I'd create a directory link ..\..\csharp to point to ..\..\..\..\foo\sdk, so the ex1.csproj would find the assembly in ..\..\csharp

Answer (score -2):

Simply add the build server location of the DLLs as a Reference path on the project. Seems to do the trick nicely and is very simple. Works only if you know the build server's folder of the DLLs.

[image]

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and it's storing the reference path details in the csproj.user file not csproj   What version of Studio are you using or is there a setting somewhere to get Studio to put the reference path details in the csproj file?

Comment: Down-voting as this only updates the csproj.user and the path is expected to exist on the developers machine when using GUI shown.