# Nuget packages - HintPath after Deployment?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have a C# class library project in VS 2017 that I'm trying to make work with Nuget packages in a somewhat strange release environment.

The project has a packages.config with standard Nuget packages such as EntityFramework 6.2.0 for example.

The project compiles fine, but the release environment is setup so that only the class library project DLL itself is deployed (no dependent DLLs).

The class library DLL needs to resolve the DLL references in a completely different directory such as C:\Dependencies, instead of the deployment location C:\ClassLibraries.

How can I resolve the dependencies that are in a completely different folder after release?

**Edit:** I already tried this HintPath Exists trick posted here, but it didn't work: 
[.csproj multiple hint paths for an assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666618/csproj-multiple-hint-paths-for-an-assembly)

**Edit 2**: I don't have access to the EXE that calls this DLL or the app.config associated with the EXE that calls this DLL.

Comment: HintPath is only used at design time by Visual Studio. 
 At run time, you need to tell the `AppDomain` where to find the assemblies with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath(@"Directory\Where\The\Dlls\Are\Stored");` as early in the application startup as possible.

Comment: Could this be done via a policy file?

Comment: I'm not familiar with policy files. Do you mean the .config file, or a manifest?

Comment: It looks like it can be [specified in the app.config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element), but I've never personally tried it.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have access to the EXE that calls my DLL or the app.config for the EXE.

Comment: You should update your question to indicate that.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: It seems you didn't use TFS, and your query is not related to TFS. So I remove tfs tag and add nuget tags.