# How to add reference to Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract in ConsoleApp to resolve Type IPropertySet

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.6.1

This feels like a real rookie mistake.

I have a ConsoleApp that I am using as part of a UWP solution (as described in [this series of posts](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/)).  In the ConsoleApp project (not the UWP project) there's this line of code...

```
string parameters = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] as string;
```

...but in my code, Visual Studio is saying that for **Values** ...

> The Type IPropertySet is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.

Visual Studio is suggesting I reference Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.  The [Windows.Foundation Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation) page says it's part of the Windows.Foundation.dll, Windows.dll assemblies.  I found this copy (C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Windows.Foundation\870ea1ce5e024b92ef1b64ebeeb38cc7) but referencing it smells wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Ah, so I noticed that if I F12'd on `LocalSettings` the top of the definition that opens has this...

```
#region Assembly Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\3.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd
#endregion
```

So I browsed to C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References and found the **Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract** folder.  There's no dll, but if you switch the visual studio reference dialog up to 'all file types' I could add a reference using the **Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd** file,(inside C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\2.0.0.0).

My code now compiles and runs.  Still not 100% sure if that's the proper way to resolve this issue though.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced this problem just now: it's an old-style (pre-`<PackageReference>`) C# project that referenced `*.winmd` files with a `<HintPath>` that was specific to the last developer's machine, who had a slightly older version of the Windows SDK installed.

There are two fixes:

### The quick-fix:

The quick-fix is to update the `<HintPath>` to point to the same-named `.winmd` file on your machine, I recommend using a tool like [Voidtools Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) to find out the new filename of the same `.winmd` file.

My `csproj` originally had this:

```
<Reference Include="Windows"> 
    <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.16299.0\Windows.winmd</HintPath> 
</Reference> 
<Reference Include="Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract"> 
    <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\3.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd</HintPath> 
<Private>False</Private> 
</Reference> 
<Reference Include="Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract"> 
    <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\5.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd</HintPath> 
<Private>False</Private> 
</Reference>
```

I changed it to this:

```
<Reference Include="Windows">
    <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.19041.0\Windows.winmd</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract">
    <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.19041.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\4.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract">
    <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.19041.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\10.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

### Better fix:

The long-term fix is [to add multiple `<HintPath>` paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666618/csproj-multiple-hint-paths-for-an-assembly) so users with different machines can still build the project:

```
<Reference Include="Windows"> 
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.16299.0\Windows.winmd')">C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.16299.0\Windows.winmd</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.19041.0\Windows.winmd')">C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.19041.0\Windows.winmd</HintPath> 
</Reference> 
<Reference Include="Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract"> 
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\3.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd')">C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\3.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd</HintPath> 
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.19041.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\4.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd')">C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.19041.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\4.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd</HintPath> 
</Reference> 
<Reference Include="Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract"> 
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\5.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd')">C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\5.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.19041.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\10.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd')">C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.19041.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\10.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd</HintPath>
</Reference>
```