# How to share class source code between several solution containing nuget references?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I see this question has been asked multiple times, but none seem to specifically highlight the issue I have at hand. I have a class library which is shared between two solutions, but it has trouble downloading nuget references.

I have two solutions which use my class library, lets call them solution1 and solution2. Directly going into these solutions and trying to compile them leads to the following error:

"The type or namespace could not be found."

It seems this is because the local package folder does not generate for the class library when I try to compile in the solution so the following local hint path in the class library .csproj file is incorrect:

```
<Hintpath> ..\packages\Dapper.1.60.6\lib\net45\Dapper.dll</HintPath>
```

There are two solutions I found to fix this problem, but both are not optimal.

1. I would have to directly open the common class library compile the code, which then generates the package folder at the hint path above. Then I can go back to solution1 or solution2 and it will compile just fine
2. I can run "Update-Package -reinstall" in package manager (from the solution1 or solution2), but that changes the hint path to bias the solition in which you run it. ie. here is the new hint path in the .csproj file:

```
<Hintpath> (base directory for solution1/2)\packages\Dapper.1.60.6\lib\net45\Dapper.dll</HintPath>
```

I would like to have it so that when I try to compile my code in "solution1" or "solution2" the package folder gets generated in the class library ie. the path "..\packages\Dapper.1.60.6\lib\net45\Dapper.dll". Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You could try using a NuGet repository and instead of relying on local packages (..\packages) consider setting up a NuGet repository (such as NuGet.org or a private repository). Once setup is complete, remove the local package reference and add the NuGet package reference from the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a better solution, we can add multiple hint paths based on condition, like the below example:

```
<Reference Include="TheAssembly">
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\..\..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('..\..\..\..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path')">..\..\..\..\..\..\..\My\Assembly\Path\TheAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    etc...
</Reference>
```

solution derived from the following question: [.csproj multiple hint paths for an assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666618/csproj-multiple-hint-paths-for-an-assembly)

as another commenter also mentioned you can also package the common class library as a nuget package, which would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people